# http: not showing in wordpress permalink setting

Tags: permalinks

http: not showing in wordpress permalink setting 
any body can advice to fix this

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go into the wp-options table. Change the URL of your site in two places to https://www.example.com . Or go into the Admin, Settings, General, and fix the URL there.  (The setting on that screen reads the value from the wp-options table.)

Make sure there are no URL settings in the wp-config.php file. Any setting in wp-config.php for the URL will override the settings in wp-options, and you will not be able to change the setting on the Settings, General page.

Comment: it helped thanks alot